# ¿Tuvo alguna vez el español una manera de diferenciar el "o" inclusivo del exclusivo?

Tags: historia, conjunciones, latín

En wikipedia se explica sobre la [conjunción disyuntiva](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunci%C3%B3n_(gram%C3%A1tica)#Conjunciones_disyuntivas):

> Sus nexos son o y u (ante palabras que empiezan por "o-" u "ho-"). Las conjunciones disyuntivas indican alternancia entre opciones. Dicha alternancia puede ser:
>
> 1. **Exclusiva** o excluyente ("¿Vienes o te quedas?").
> 2. **Abierta**, inclusiva o incluyente (¿"*Estudias* **o** *trabajas*?", en el sentido de que pueden hacerse las dos cosas)
> 3. **De equivalencia denominativa**, cuando se unen dos expresiones con idéntico valor denominativo: "*Los médicos estudian la dispepsia*** o** *digestión lenta*". "*Cervantes* **o** *El manco de Lepant*o". "*Don Álvaro* **o** *La fuerza del sino*".

En [esta pregunta](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/40/whats-the-difference-between-vel-aut-ve-et-cetera/73) se menciona la existencia en latín de ciertas conjunciones que entiendo son equivalentes al "o", pero con sus funciones separadas:

- **aut**: disyunción exclusiva

  > Licet tibi habere aut vim aut laetitia -> Puedes tener poder o felicidad pero no ambos.
- **vel**: disyunción inclusiva

  > Licet tibi habere vel vim vel laetitia -> Puedes tener poder o felicidad, o ambos, si lo deseas.

A veces pienso que si bien el contexto ayuda para decidir si una "o" es exclusiva o inclusiva, esta conjunción puede llegar a ser ambigua, por lo que me pareció curioso que el latín si tuviera una particula distinta para cada caso.

**¿Tuvo el español alguna vez conjunciones disyuntivas distintas así como el latín? Y si nunca las tuvo, o si las perdió en algún momento, ¿por qué pasó eso?**
Y agregando la pregunta del comentario de @walen: ¿existe alguna manera hoy en día de especificar esta diferencia en español, más allá del contexto?

Comment: @walen En una pregunta es raro, por eso he borrado el comentario, iba a redactarlo de otra manera porque no vale para todos los casos

Comment: @walen - Ya sea  hago pescado para la cena, o [bien] hago pollo.  *No* voy a hacer dos menus diferentes.  Escoge, por favor.  *Lo precedente es lo mejor que he logrado con la exclusiva.*

Comment: I was told that an exclusive 'or' would be with an accent: "ó". Although I did not find any reliable source, I have met a lot of people who have used it in this way.

Btw I have found a very nice article related to this topic: https://gramatica.usc.es/att/tomas.jimenez/Jimenez1986a.pdf

Comment: dios, me ha explotado el cerebro con "¿Estudias o trabajas?", nunca me habia dado cuenta que la pregunta puede ser una de "si o no" o de elección. :S

Comment: @Abend la ó con tilde es solo una convención ortografía que era obligatoria en todos los casos hace muchos años, y solo entre cifras hace menos años.

Comment: Ante el evidente deseo de tanta gente, propongo: ¿no deberíamos **inventarla**? Es cuestión de que empiece a usarse...

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta de que la "o" inclusiva o exclusiva la tenemos en el lenguaje, pero en la expresión oral. Fijaos en la entonación que le dais a la frase "¿Estudias o trabajas?" cuando esperas que la respuesta sea "sí" (es decir, si estás preguntando si hace cualquiera de las dos cosas), o cuando esperas que la respuesta sea una elección. En el segundo caso la pronunciación se parece más a "¿Estudias? ¿O trabajas?", con una caída de la entonación en la segunda parte.

Answer (score 6):

La o exclusiva en español se puede expresar sin ambigüedades utilizando la construcción "o ... o ...". Por ejemplo "Un bit puede tener o un valor 1 o un valor 0".

En latín la conjunción "aut" puede expresar disyunción exclusiva e inclusive, es por eso que su uso permaneció hasta ahora en la forma "o". "vei" por el contrario no era capaz de expresar la disyunción exclusiva y su uso se restringía completamente al uso inclusivo.

De *Rubio (1976) Introducción a la sintaxis estructural del latin II* :

> **vei**: Puede usarse siempre que se trate de expresar senciallamente la disyunción o alternativa entre dos términos, tanto si se trata de
>   términos que se excluyen como de términos semánticamente unidos y
>   hasta equivalentes o indiferentes a la elección"

Hay una buena explicación en este [texto](https://minerva.usc.es/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10347/4895/pg_165-182_verba13.pdf?sequence=1) de Tomás Jimenez Julia. En este texto se muestra también la evolución del significado de "aut"/o a lo largo de la historia del español

Answer (score 0):

En los cursos de lógica solíamos usar "o" para la disyunción inclusiva, y "o bien" para la disyunción exclusiva.

Wordreference sugiere traducir "o bien" como "either or", que es el significado que buscamos.
http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=o+bien

Answer (score 0):

No se hace cuánto tiempo atrás fue, pero en español se usaba "o" para conectar dos frases que podían ser incluyentes o excluyentes y, se usaba "ó" cuando la conjunción se volvía excluyente (una de ambas, nunca las dos). Incluso se usaba "ó" cuando eran números, para así hacer énfasis en que no había ambigüedad (era una regla obligatoria: la o siempre lleva tilde entre números).

No estoy 100% seguro pues las leyes se elaboran y proponen y van siendo aprobadas y rigidizadas con los años. Según mi información, los cambios en este sentido fueron en los años 50.

Comment: Normalmente se usaba la tilde en _o_ para separa números en textos manuscritos (para que _3 o 4_ no pareciera _304_, por ejemplo). Parece que [ya no se usa](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/850/1674).

Answer (score -1):

Algo interesante es que la "o" exclusiva no existe en español, esta tiene que componerse con el contexto, o se debe de entender en el sentido de la pregunta.

Hay un viejo chiste de programadores que dice:

> Sabes que eres programador si acaba de nacer tu hijo, y la mamá te pregunta *"¿es niño o niña?"* y tú respondes: *"sí"*.

Para hacer evidente la "o" exclusiva en español, se tiene que dividir la oración en dos partes para hacer énfasis en las opciones:

> ¿Fue niño o fue niña?

O también podemos agregar una "o" al inicio de la primera opción, observa la diferencia a continuación (y observa cómo la utilicé al inicio de esta misma oración):

> *Puedes elegir azul o rojo.*
>
> > Esto indica que puede elegir cualquier color o ambos.
>
> *O azul o rojo.*
>
> > Esto indica que solo puede elegir uno de los dos colores.

Utilicemos tus ejemplos para este resultado:

> *¿Vienes o te quedas?*
>
> > Ahora lo transformaremos en dos preguntas:
> >
> > > *¿Vas a venir? o ¿te vas a quedar?*
> > >
> > > > Claramente solo hay una respuesta.

Ahora transformemos a una afirmación la pregunta "¿Estudias o trabajas?":

> *O estudias o trabajas.*
>
> > Obviamente la persona en cuestión se sentirá confundida pues hace ambas cosas.

En la wiki también puedes encontrar este mismo ejemplo:

> *"O llamó Pablo o Carlos"*.

Comment: No sé si se puede usar una conjunción para unir dos preguntas de esta forma: _«¿Vas a venir? o ¿te vas a quedar?»_. Lo normal sería: ¿Vas a venir o te vas a quedar?. Aunque en ese caso, como en el chiste de niño o niña, la propia frase excluye una de las dos opciones, o vienes o te quedas, no puedes hacer ambas cosas a la vez.